# Библиотека для авторизации через соцсети

Tags: javascript, java, auth

Хочу чтобы на фронте можно было залогиниться через соцсети. Все что нужно - это чтобы в итоге на сервер (сервер на Java) я получил что-то вроде составного user id из пары "социальная сеть" - "айди в соцсети", по которому будет организована сессия.

В целом в задаче ничего сложного нет, у соцсетей есть апи. Единственная сложность - соцсетей много, работа монотонная и скучная )

Есть ли какое-нибудь готовое бесплатное решение на эту тему? Чтобы красивенько и в две строчки ) Погуглил немного - что-то такое есть у firebase, но решение не бесплатное.

Comment: Бесплатно бывает только сыр в мышеловке.

Comment: То есть вы платите, скажем, за Spring/React/MySql?

Comment: За это платит заказчик. Продолжал гуглить дальше, если что-то нагуглмшь ещё то добавишь в вопрос.

Comment: https://github.com/scribejava/scribejava - посмотрите сюда. хороший проект с большими возможностями. не то,чтобы совсем 2 строчки, но явно не с нуля все писать. ну и спринг имееет пакет для соц сетей, тоже не стоит забывать